# Blazor WebAssembly project fails to build

Tags: visual-studio, blazor-webassembly

I create a Blazor WebAssembly using the Visual Studio 2022 Template for Blazor WebAssembly, selecting .NET 7.0. But building the project (no modifications) gives me a number of errors. One of the errors is

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages    blazor-app  D:\Projects\blazor-app\blazor-app\blazor-app.csproj 1

Does someone know how I can fix my configuration so this will work?

Comment: Did you disable the default nuget.org in your sources?

Comment: I am not sure how or why I need to. The project was generated entirely through the template. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: I didn't mean you need to disable it. Quite the opposite actually. And it's got nothing to do with the template used to create your project. Please check the configured NuGet sources on your machine, as I suspect that NuGet.org is either missing or disabled.

Answer (score 0):

As was commented the source for NuGet.Org was missing.